# Is there away to completely override a line of code based on a condition set?

Tags: swift

I creating this app for my church and one feature is a prayer wall. I am using firebase as my database integrated with google sign in. When a user post a prayer request it displays their display names amongst other things. I implemented a switch and some line of code to change the display name to anonymous if the switch is on. That works however it adds anonymous after the display name. Please see the examples below.

I am really new to swift and I am self taught this is my first app, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@IBAction func didPostPrayerRequest(_ sender: Any) {    
    var userInfo = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName

    if privacyFilter.isOn {
        userInfo?.append("anonymous")
    }

    let prayerPosted:[String: Any] = ["praydate": [".sv":"timestamp"], "prayer": prayerPostText.text!,"username":userInfo!]

    prayerRef?.child("Prayers").childByAutoId().setValue(prayerPosted)

    print("Any")

    //Dismiss popover
    presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxnFD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply overwrite the value using `userInfo = "anonymous"` instead of appending to it.

Comment: Thats Awesome!! It worked! Thank you for taking the time to read my question and responding. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @NeilLeon if this answer resolved your issue, please accept it (green tick it).